# C help for a program to grade a reading level

Tags: c, cs50

I am doing this program that will supposedly act as a program that shows the reading grade level of a given text based on The Coleman-Liau index. So far I have done the letter, word counter, and sentence counter functions right. The problem is when I plug them into the The Coleman-Liau index formula, the result doesn't show the correct answers.

I suspect I did some mistakes with the way I interpret this into the formula:  ***L is the average number of letters per 100 words in the text, and S is the average number of sentences per 100 words in the text.*** as shown in my code below. Or does it probably have anything to do with the way I put float before the L and S?

No matter what I do the S will always produce 0.000000 as the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    //ask for user input
    char *text = get_string("Text: ");
//** letter counter function that prints the Letter-count in the text
//**build a word counter function and print the wordcount in the text
//**build a sentence counter function and print the sentence-count in the text

//Put everything into formula
    float L = (letter_counter / word_counter) * 100.00;
    float S = (sentence_counter / word_counter) * 100.00;
    float index  = (0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8;
    int rounded_index = round(index);

 //If the index is greater than or equal to 16, then print Grade 16+
    if (rounded_index >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }

    //If the index is less than 1, print before grade 1
    if (rounded_index < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }

    //Else print the index given by the coleman-liau index computation above
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", rounded_index);

    }
}
```

Any advice/suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what types are `letter_counter`, `word_counter`, and `sentence_counter`? (and also relevant: what values have they had while you've been testing this?)

Comment: @moreON, I am pretty sure I set them as int. The function looks like this:  int sentence_counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; text[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?')
        {
            sentence_counter++;
        }
    }

Comment: That pretty much explains it then. The result of dividing an `int` by an `int` is an `int` (the floor of the division). Try using `( 1.0 * letter_counter / word_counter ) `, etc. `1.0` is a double, so `1.0 * some_int` is also a double. Can use `1.0f` to get a float instead of double.

Comment: @moreON but when I change the int to float in the functions, I got these messages: array subscript is not an integer

Comment: That's completely reasonable. Array subscripts have to be integers. See the recommendations in the previous comment.

Comment: @moreON, that works like a charm! Thank you for this! I would never had thought that this could be the problem before :((

Comment: You can also write `(double)letter_counter / word_counter` to perform floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @moreON Would you like to make an answer for this?

Comment: If you add information (as the definitions of `..._counter`), please [edit] your question. Down here in the comments it's lost.